# Kubernetes - Unable to delete service

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm trying to delete a service using `kubectl delete svc httpd` but it keeps getting re-created. I used a crd to implement all the pods and services.

Any idea what could be managing this service? I've checked deployments but can't find any deployments managing this httpd service. What else could it be and how can I find out?

I know if pods are deleted, deployments can recreate. But what about service?

```
[root@ip-172-31-38-132 ~]# kubectl  get svc
NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
httpd                       ClusterIP   100.70.xxx.xx    <none>        8080/TCP            5m49s
```

`kubectl describe svc httpd`:

```
Name:              httpd
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app=forts
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          name=httpd
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                100.70.xxx.xx
IPs:               100.70.xxx.xx
Port:              http  8080/TCP
TargetPort:        8080/TCP
Endpoints:         100.96.xxx.xx:8080
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I want to know what can recreate a service if deleted. I know if pods are deleted, deployments can recreate. But what about service?

Comment: There should be a deployment associated with the service. Please describe the service and check for any underlying deployments in the same namespace for this. You can run `kubectl describe svc httpd` and update the question with output.

Comment: I've added the output of `kubectl describe svc httpd`.

Comment: `kubectl get pods` there should be pod having name httpd

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. Were you able to find a fix? @user630702